# How to send an ASCII string via SerialPort

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, ascii

I am new in VB.NET.

My question is about how to send a ASCII string via SerialPort.

I want to send this: `?A\r` via ASCII and receive a response via HEX

I try this

```vb
Dim arr1() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("?A\r")
SerialPort1.Write(arr1, 0, arr1.Length)
```

[image]

But it does not work.

I am using RealTerm program.

Comment: `\r` is a C-style escape sequence that VB does not have. You need to use `"?A" & vbCr` for that.

Comment: thanks work good now i changed this
"?A" & vbCr